# Como se comportam o StringBuffer() e o StringBuilder()?

Tags: java, debug

**Problema e Mistério:**

---

```
StringBuffer y = new StringBuffer("Eduardo");
```

Estou usando um `StringBuffer`, pois preciso acrescentar alguns valores depois a ela. Estava fazendo debug e observei que existem um espaços em branco no final. Observe a imagem:

[image: Espaços no StringBuffer]
*Imagem 1: Espaços adicionais no StringBuffer.*

---

O mesmo acontece quando uso o `StringBuilder`, alguém saber por que esses espaços são incrementados?

Existem alguns aspectos entre `StringBuilder` e `StringBuffer`. Como usar o `Builder` quando não envolve `Thread`. Acredito não ter invertido.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Os espaços em branco são para aprimorar a performance na hora de concatenar as Strings. Por isso que é um "buffer".

Por exemplo: se vc concatena duas Strings assim: "abc" + "def", o Java vai criar, além desses dois objetos String, um terceiro objeto contendo o resultado "abcdef". No entanto, ao usar o buffer, o Java vai jogar os chars 'd', 'e' e 'f' dentro dos espaços vazios do buffer e atualizar aquele 'count' da sua figura para refletir o novo tamanho do conjunto. Isso é uma operação muito mais rápida.

Caso os espaços em branco não sejam suficientes, o Java vai aumentar automaticamente o tamanho do buffer para você.

Tamanho esse que, aliás, você pode configurar no [construtor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#StringBuffer%28int%29). Isso é bom porque custa um pouco (em termos de performance) para o Java redimensionar o buffer.

Comment: Lógico que, no meu exemplo, a operação não é "muito mais rápida", pois fiz uma concatenação trivial de duas strings. Agora tente isso num loop grande o bastante e você vai sentir a diferença.

Answer (score 13):

## A hierarquia

As classes [`java.lang.StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) e [`java.lang.StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) possuem exatamente a mesma interface estendem `java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder`, que possui dois atributos principais:

```java
char value[];
int count;
```

Ali são armazenados os caracteres e o tamanho real do mesmo.

## Sobre o *Buffer*

`String` é um tipo que armazena um conjunto de caracteres. Ela é imutável, isto é, não pode ter o conteúdo modificado, assim como seu tamanho.

O problema com isso é que para criar novas Strings, por exemplo, através da concatenação de duas ou mais Strings, uma nova String como o tamanho total delas deve ser criada em memória. Se várias dessas operações forem executadas em sequência, a JVM precisará alocar novos blocos de memória e executar o Garbage Collector para desalocar o que não é usado a todo momento. Isso é muito "custoso" em termos de desempenho.

O `StringBuffer` surge para resolver o problema. Um `StringBuffer` nada mais é do que uma *String* com um *Buffer*, isto é, um espaço reservado para novos caracteres que pode ser modificado e torna desnecessário, até certo ponto, alocar mais memória a todo momento.

O buffer é simplesmente um vetor de caracteres maior do que o conteúdo real. Por exemplo, o buffer pode ter 1000 posições e a String real apenas 500. Isso é controlado pelo atributo `count`. Neste exemplo, poderíamos adicionar ainda mais 500 caracteres sem degradar o desempenho do programa.

## O tamanho inicial

Em muitas situações é importante definir o tamanho inicial do buffer com um tamanho médio do que se pretende usar.

Ao fazer `new StringBuffer()` ou `new StringBuilder()`, isto é, sem definir um tamanho inicial, estamos subutilizando a classe. A capacidade inicial do buffer é de apenas 16 caracteres.

Isso significa que, se adicionarmos mais de 16 caracteres, um novo *buffer* terá que ser alocado.

## Aumentando o tamanho

Ao estourar a capacidade do buffer o próximo será criado com o dobro do tamanho. Veja o cálculo da nova capacidade do buffer no método `expandCapacity` da classe `AbstractStringBuilder`:

```java
void expandCapacity(int minimumCapacity) {
    int newCapacity = (value.length + 1) * 2;
    if (newCapacity < 0) {
        newCapacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    } else if (minimumCapacity > newCapacity) {
        newCapacity = minimumCapacity;
    }
    value = Arrays.copyOf(value, newCapacity);
}
```

## `StringBuffer` ou `StringBuilder`?

Esta é uma dúvida comum. Olhe o Javadoc (links estão no início da resposta) e note que ambas tem exatamente a mesma interface, isto é, os mesmos métodos e assinaturas de métodos.

Qual a diferença? Vamos analisar um método básico nas duas versões, o `append(String)`.

A versão no `StringBuilder` é:

```java
public StringBuilder append(String str) {
    super.append(str);
    return this;
}
```

E a versão no `StringBuffer` é:

```java
public synchronized StringBuffer append(String str) {
    super.append(str);
    return this;
}
```

Notou a diferença? É o **`synchronized`**!

Dizemos que a classe `StringBuffer` é *sincronizada*, enquanto a classe `StringBuilder` *não é sincronizada*.

## Sincronizado vs. Não Sincronizado

Quais as vantagens e desvantagens em ser ou não sincronizado?

Quando uma classe é sincronizada, ela é mais própria para trabalhar em ambientes com várias threads, por exemplo, num servidor de aplicação que atende a vários usuários ao mesmo tempo. Imagine várias threads escrevendo um log em memória, por exemplo.

Nesse caso, somente uma thread por vez pode adicionar conteúdo ao `StringBuffer`. O problema é que isso gera também bloqueios indesejados na execução, pois nem sempre estamos modificando a classe.

Se várias threads querem apenas ler alguma informação da classe, então a sincronização está atrasando eles sem motivo. Só para citar um exemplo, a classe `StringBuffer` tem o método de busca `indexOf` sincronizado.

Já quando uma classe não é sincronizada, ela não é adequada para ser usada concorrentemente por mais de uma thread, porém ela obtém o máximo de aproveitamento para ser modificada por uma única thread e também para ser usada no modo de leitura por várias threads.

Como regra geral, se o objeto será usado apenas no escopo de um método, não sendo compartilhado, opta-se sempre pelo `StringBuilder`, que foi criado justamente com esse propósito.

Já se o objeto for compartilhado de alguma forma com outras classes e for possível que alguém o use em múltiplas threadas, o `StringBuffer` é mais adequado.

Esse raciocínio de aplica a diversas outras classes da JVM. Veja por exemplo, as classes [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) (sincronizada), [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (não sincronizada) e [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) (sincronizada apenas para alteração, mas não para leitura).

Por isso, é evidente a importância de conhecer bem as APIs da linguagem antes de sair usando sempre as mesmas soluções indiscriminadamente.

---

Para maiores detalhes, ver minha [outra resposta aqui no SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16064/227).

Answer (score 6):

Isso tem relação com os tamanhos padrão e a forma como o buffer interno é incrementado, tanto para o `StringBuffer` quanto para o `StringBuilder`.

Você consegue ver isso porque está inspecionando o campo `value` do objeto, onde a string é construida e armazenada. Repare, de qualquer forma, que o tamanho real da sua string é mantido no campo `count`.

Answer (score 5):

Apenas para acrescentar, se olha na classe `StringBuilder` está assim:

```
/**
 * Constructs a string builder that contains the same characters
 * as the specified <code>CharSequence</code>. The initial capacity of
 * the string builder is <code>16</code> plus the length of the
 * <code>CharSequence</code> argument.
 *
 * @param      seq   the sequence to copy.
 * @throws    NullPointerException if <code>seq</code> is <code>null</code>
 */
public StringBuilder(CharSequence seq) {
    this(seq.length() + 16);
    append(seq);
}

public StringBuilder append(Object obj) {
    return append(String.valueOf(obj));
}

public StringBuilder append(String str) {
    super.append(str);
    return this;
}
```

Repare que no construtor ele deixa 16 caracteres em branco inicialmente, exatamente a quantidade de espaços em branco que está depois do `Eduardo`, no seu exemplo. Esse é o tamanho que é deixado como `buffer` por padrão, mas como dito em outra resposta você pode passar o tamanho inicial no `StringBuffer` ou `StringBuilder`.

Esse espaço sobrando faz que o tamanho não necessariamente fique mudando a cada inserção de valores no seu objeto, e ao mesmo tempo não tem um sobra tão grande assim ao ponto de consumir um espaço significativo de memória.