# Selecionar string aleatoriamente

Tags: java, string, random

Preciso de um modo para criar aleatoriamente uma string entre algumas opções.

Digamos que tenho as strings "A" "B" e "C", seria possível um modo para o Java escolher aleatoriamente?

Comment: gera um numero aleatório tira o módulo e atribui o numero a uma string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basta usar o método [`shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) disponível para uso em coleções. Este método é feito para ordenar aleatoriamente elementos de uma coleção.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> letras = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C");
    Collections.shuffle(letras);
    System.out.println(letras);
}
```

Para criar a *string* se for poucos elementos basta fazer uma concatenação simples, caso contrário basta usar um [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) ([entenda porque o StringBuilder](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16050/string-e-sua-efici%C3%AAncia) é importante quando há muitos elementos para concatenar na *string*).

---

O AP disse que interpretamos a pergunta de forma errada, então a solução é pegar a primeira letra da *string* gerada conforme o Bacco comentou abaixo

Ainda existe outra solução:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String letras = "ABC";  
    Random gerador = new Random();  
    System.out.println(letras.charAt(gerador.nextInt(letras.length())));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/4FiexS). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gsnfnlyn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/RamdomFirstLetter.java).

Comment: como funciona esse método @bigown?
desconheço ele, porque seria melhor que minha solução?
pode explicar por favor? se quiser crio uma pergunta só pra isso!

Comment: @Joannis tem o link com a documentação dele. Ele é melhor porque já está pronto e não precisa reinventar a roda. Como o nome diz ele embaralha aleatoriamente os elementos de uma coleção qualquer. Justamente o que o AP quer. Os criadores do Java provavelmente fizeram da melhor forma possível. A sua tem um inconveniente que adicional que é preciso mudar um código mais complexo para mudar ou adicionar um valor.

Comment: valew, (eu n tinha visto o link para a documentação, vou dar uma olhada)
vai meu voto a favor =D

Comment: @Joannis note que a sua e a outra resposta estão corretas (pelo menos me pareceu), tanto que votei nelas.

Comment: sim, eu vi, eu e ele postamos quase ao mesmo tempo, 
entendi a resposta dele também. só não tinha entendido a sua por não conhecer o suffle. (sou novo em java)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda @bigowmn , mas na verdade não quero reordenar, mas sim escolhe uma das 3 aleatoriamente

Comment: @user3511983 mas é aleatório o shuffle. Basta pegar a primeira delas, que vai ser uma aleatória depois do _shuffle_. Shuffle é "embaralhar".

Comment: @user3511983 Parece que não foi o que perguntou. Note que ninguém entendeu isto. Vou colocar outra solução mas o que o Bacco disse resolve o que você quer.

Comment: O segundo parâmetro de `substring` (no segundo exemplo) não deve ser `1`, pois ele representa o final (*end index*) e não o tamanho (*length*).

Comment: @utluiz é verdade, muita linguagem na cabeça :)

Comment: Nem me fale. Cada linguagem faz substring diferente. :D

Answer (score 4):

Tenta usar essa função

```
// Determia as letras que poderão estar presente nas chaves  
String letras = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVYWXZ";  

Random random = new Random();  

String armazenaChaves = "";  
int index = -1;  
for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {  
   index = random.nextInt( letras.length() );  
   armazenaChaves += letras.substring( index, index + 1 );  
}  
System.out.println(armazenaChaves);
```

Answer (score 3):

Gere um numero aleatório com a função `random`, tire o módulo e a partir daí forme sua string.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Random1 { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //instância um objeto da classe Random usando o 
        //construtor padrão 
        Random gerador = new Random(); 
        int x = gerador.nextInt();
        String string;
        switch (x%3){
        case 0:
            string = "A";
            break;
        case 1:
            string = "B";
            break;
        case 2:
            string = "C";
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para selecionar uma `String` entre muitas num *array*:

```
String[] opcoes = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "Z" };
String selecionada = opcoes[new Random().nextInt(opcoes.length)];
```

Para fazer o mesmo com uma lista:

```
List<String> opcoes = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "Z");
String selecionada = opcoes.get(new Random().nextInt(opcoes.size()));
```