# Número máximo de carateres em uma String e StringBuffer em Java

Tags: java, string

Qual o limite máximo de caráteres que os tipos `String` e `StringBuffer` suportam em Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O limite teórico é o valor máximo de um `int` - `2^31-1` - já que as strings são representadas internamente por um array de `char`, e a forma de indexar esse array é através de um `int`. Entretanto, o que vai limitar na prática o tamanho das strings é o espaço físico (memória RAM), que certamente será bem menor que esse limite teórico.

Não sei como o `StringBuffer` é representado internamente, mas ainda que ele possua representação capaz de suportar mais do que o limite mencionado, a forma de se referir a um caractere em particular (`charAt`) ainda utiliza um `int`, de modo que pode-se considerar o mesmo limite na prática.

Comment: Assim qual seria a principal diferença entre ambos?

Comment: Uma `String` é imutável, de modo que você pode compartilhar referências da mesma livremente. Um `StringBuffer` e `StringBuilder` são mutáveis, você edita a sequência de caracteres à vontade para - só no final - transformar em uma `String` (*se* precisar). O `StringBuffer` é *thread-safe*, e o `StringBuilder` não é. Mais informações sobre seu funcionamento [nessa pergunta relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7671/215)

Comment: para documentação: StringBuffer é implementado usando arrays, e de acordo com a especificação, no que diz sobre arrays: `The variables contained in an array have no names; instead they are referenced by array access expressions that use non-negative integer index values`.

Comment: @wryel Quando disse que não sabia como `StringBuffer` funcionava internamente, me referia à possibilidade dele usar arrays de strings por exemplo - o que implicaria numa capacidade total teórica maior que o tamanho de um `int`. Mas você está certo, é apenas um array de caracteres mesmo, com "espaço sobrando".

Comment: Bom. Agora o assunto pra mim é perceber a baixo nível o que significa um `String` ser imutável.

Comment: @Cold Nunca refleti profundamente sobre o assunto, simplesmente tomei que "não existem métodos na API de `String` para modificá-la" e fiquei satisfeito com isso... Agora, na prática, pode ser que existam otimizações feitas pela JVM ou coisas do tipo. Se tiver interesse, sugiro abrir uma pergunta separada, assim quem tiver mais conhecimento no assunto poderá responder (eu não tenho).

Comment: Questionando o verdadeiro significado de `String` ser imutavel @mgibsonbr?

Comment: @Cold isto pode lhe ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15510/o-que-imut%C3%A1vel-realmente-significa/15512#15512

Answer (score 2):

O limite maximo que ambos suportam é 2^31- 1 (ou aproximadamente 2 bilhões)

O StringBuffer te da eficacia na concatenação de String

Comment: E qual a diferença entre ambos se possuem a mesma capacidade?

Comment: http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/post/2124-java_diferencas_entre_as_classes_string_stringbuffer_e_stringbuilder

Comment: http://www.devmedia.com.br/diferencas-entre-string-stringbuilder-e-stringbuffer-em-java/29865