# Como eu consigo separar uma string por exemplo 36529874 de dois em dois sem ter nenhum carcter de separação por exemplo 36.52.98.74

Tags: java, string

Estou pegando o IMEI do celular e tenho que dividi-lo em grupos de 2 caracteres para eu convertê-los para hexa depois.

Essa String vem sem separador, os números vêm junto, por exemplo 36529874 e eu queria separá-los em grupos de dois números. Assim pego a String divido os dois primeiros e converto em hexa, divido os dois segundos e converto em hexa, divido os dois terceiros e converto em hexa. Após converter esses pares em hexa quero usar somente alguns para mostrar na tela. Como eu posso fazer isso? Sou iniciante, procurei uma  solução mas não achei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como se trata de uma String com um tamanho fixo e a saída deve seguir o mesmo padrão, sugiro fazer da forma mais simples possível:

```
public class ConverteIMEI {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String IMEI = "36529874";
        StringBuilder IMEI_convertido = new StringBuilder();
        IMEI_convertido.append(
                Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(IMEI.substring(0, 2)))).
                append(".").append(
                Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(IMEI.substring(2, 4)))).
                append(".").append(
                Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(IMEI.substring(4, 6)))).
                append(".").append(
                Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(IMEI.substring(6, 8))));
        System.out.println("IMEI: " + IMEI + "; IMEI_convertido: " + IMEI_convertido);
    }
}
```

Saída:

> IMEI: 36529874; IMEI_convertido: 24.34.62.4a

Usei o StringBuilder pois são *várias* operações de `append()` então se usasse String seriam criados muito objetos do tipo String para concatenar no resultado. Mas como disse, por se tratar de um problema simples se usar várias String também é aceitável.

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/YIgPML)

Comment: Essa saída ta correta: `IMEI: 36529874; IMEI_convertido: 24.34.62.4a`?

Comment: Bom, ele disse que quer converter para hexa. O título dele deixa meio confuso pois parece que ele quer quer a saída seja `36.52.98.74`, mas na verdade ele diz que a entrada não tem a separação do tipo `36.52.98.74`. Foi isso que eu entendi da pergunta.

Comment: Isso mesmo Math!

Comment: @kaamis a parte que você diz `Após converter esses pares em hexa quero usar somente alguns para mostrar na tela.`, depende de quais caracteres você quer exibir, mas pode fazer usando o `substring()` novamente.

Comment: @Math, entendi, é essa pergunta está bem ruim mesmo, fica a dica para o AP, tentar melhorar esta pergunta e as futuras.

Comment: Ok, eu entendi @Math muito obrigado. Só poderia me explicar o que é esse comando `append` e o `StringBuilder`? Desculpe pela pergunta @Fernando.

Comment: @kaamis Variáveis do tipo `String` são imutáveis, ou seja, a cada concatenação uma nova variável do tipo `String` é criada e as anteriores (utilizadas para concatenar) ficam a espera do Garbage Collector vir limpá-las da memória. Logo, quando se faz uma operação que envolve a criação de muitas `Strings` o ideal é usar o `StringBuilder` que é similar a classe `String`, porém é mutável, isso resulta em um consumo menor de memória RAM.

Comment: É possível que no meu exemplo não faça muita diferença usar `Strings` ou `StringBuilder` pois se trata de um trecho pequeno de código, mas por costume eu usei o `StringBuilder`. Veja também essas questões: [Qual o meio mais apropriado para se concatenar strings?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124/3117) (é de C#, mas ajuda a entender), [Como se comportam o StringBuffer() e o StringBuilder()?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7671/3117) e [String e sua eficiência](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16050/3117)

Comment: Ok, muito obrigada pessoal. Desculpem meu comportamento leigo.

Answer (score 4):

Pode utilizar [Regex Java](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) assim:

```
String test = "36529874";

// regex para números de 2 em 2
// [0-9] = todos os números de 0 a 9
// {2} = agrupar de 2 em 2
// Você poderia também utilizar simplesmente isso: {2}, ele irá pegar de 2 em 2 sem considerar se é numero ou não
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{2}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
List<String> tokens = new LinkedList<String>();
while(m.find())
{
  String token = m.group(0);
  tokens.add(token);
}
for (String string : tokens) {
    System.out.println(string); // out 36 52 98 74
}
```

Comment: Muito desperdício usar regex para algo simples assim.

Comment: O que mais eu poderia usar @LuisHenrique ?

Comment: O que seria os parâmetros `("[0-9]{2}");` da linha `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{2}");` ? @Fernando

Comment: Substring resolve seu problema.

Comment: EU vi aqui @LuisHenrique é mais prático. Se puder deixar um exemplo seria legal rs mas obrigada!

Comment: @kaamis ,editei como nova informação a respeito de '[0-9]{2}'

Comment: @LuisHenrique, não considero desperdício utilizar Regex, já que Regex é uma das formas mais rápidas e eficientes de manipulação de strings, e ainda é muito mais auto documentável (para quem conhece expressões regulares) do que qualquer algoritmo com `substring` e alguns `for's` que faça algo similar. Mas por favor poste sua versão com `substring`, para que possamos ter outra opção.

Comment: Pena que eu vi o comentário só um ano depois. Rápida e eficiente não é. Só é prática. Troca-se eficiência e velocidade justamente pela praticidade de resolver em menos linhas.

Answer (score 3):

Pode separar utilizando substring.

```
String imei = "36529874";
int size = imei.length()/2;
String[] grupos = new String[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    grupos[i] = imei.substring(i*2, i*2+2);
}
```

Terá a resposta no vetor `grupos` em ordem.

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/6UQmcX)