# Quando usar StringBuilder e StringBuffer no lugar de concatenação com operador "+" em Java?

Tags: java, string, operadores, concatenação-de-string

Quais os benefícios de concatenar uma *string* utilizando `StringBuilder` ou `StringBuffer` em vez de utilizar simplesmente o operador `+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende de como usa o operador de `+`. Se for uma concatenação simples, feita tudo de uma vez em uma única expressão, ele é eficiente e pode usar sem medo, isto é convertido para um método que faz a concatenação de forma apropriada e rápida.

Já li alguma coisa de otimizações que mesmo usando mais de uma expressão ele pode ser eficiente, mas não conte com isso, é detalhe de implementação específica.

Se for um **laço** onde você vai fazendo várias sucessivas concatenações (geralmente acima de 4) aí o resultado será de ruim a trágico porque vai fazendo uma nova alocação na memória e cópia do texto a cada concatenação realizada, ou seja o custo vai crescendo exponencialmente. Aí deve usar um dos dois métodos de construção de *string* conforme [Como se comportam o StringBuffer() e o StringBuilder()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7671/101).

A resposta aceita na pergunta *linkada* está simplista demais e beira o erro, mas ela serve para ver a diferença entre essas duas estruturas de dados de *string*.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger bem confuso isso, não? Tanto que beira o erro.

Answer (score -1):

Como Maniero bem colocou, StringBuilder e StringBuffer devem ser utilizados quando for necessário realizar concatenações sucessivas. Isso evita desperdício de memória.

O que queria acrescentar é uma observação quanto a decisão entre uma e outra. StringBuilder é mais rápido, porém o StringBuffer é thread-safe.